# Norm of the adjoint operator

Tags: operator-theory, normed-spaces

> If $T$ sends $L^r(\mathbb R^n)$ to itself with norm $B$ for some $1< r\le \infty$ then what can we say about the norm of its adjoint $T^*$ which sends $L^{r'}(\mathbb R^n)$ to itself where $r'=\frac{r}{r-1}$

$T$ is given by convolution with $K$, i.e. $T(f)=\int K(x-y)f(y)dy$ and the adjoint is defined by $\langle T(f)|g\rangle=\int T(f)\bar g\ dx=\int f \overline{T^*(g)}\ dx=\langle f|T^*(g)\rangle$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The adjoint of an operator always has the same norm as the operator itself. Note that for $g \in L^{r'}(\mathbf R^n)$, we have
\begin{align*}
  \def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}\def\<#1>{\left<#1\right>}
  \def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|}
   \norm{T^*(g)} &= \sup_{\norm{f}_r \le 1} \abs{\<T^*g,f>}\\
                 &= \sup_{\norm f_r\le 1}\abs{\<g,Tf>}\\
                 &\le \sup_{\norm f_r\le 1}\norm g\norm{Tf}\\
                 &= \norm g \norm T.
\end{align*}
Hence $\norm{T^*}\le \norm{T}$.

As $T = T^{**}$, we have 
$$ \norm T = \norm{T^{**}} \stackrel!\le \norm{T^*} \le \norm{T}$$
where for the first inequality (marked with !), we applied the above for $T^*$.

Therefore $\norm T = \norm{T^*}$.